# In Grails, how do I get a property for a relationship on a Spring Security user?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm using Spring Security. Let's say I have a `User` that belongs to a `Store`. The `Store` has a property that determines if it has an online shop or not:

```
class Store {
    ...
    boolean isOnline
    ...
}

class User {
    ...
    def belongsTo = [ store: Store ]
    ...
}
```

In a global navbar template that's displayed on every single page, I'd like to display a link if the currently-logged-in user's `Store` is online shoppable. I'm currently using this code in the toolbar template:

```
<g:set var="userId" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'id') as Long}"/>
<g:set var="user" value="${User.get(userId)}"/>

<g:if test="${user.store.isOnline}">
    <li>
        <g:link controller="store" action="redirect">Shop Online</g:link>
    </li>
</g:if>
```

Although this code works, is there a better way of handling this logic? I don't particularly like that I'm executing this code for **every** page render, and I especially don't like that I'm using `User.get()` directly in the view.

In other words, is there anything equivalent to `springSecurityService.currentUser` for a view that allows me to grab the actual `User` object and travel down its relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move this logic to a filter:

```
class UserFilters {

   SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

   def filters = {
       loadUser(controller: '*', action: '*') {
           before = {
              def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
              request.setAttribute('currentUser', user)
           }
       }
   }

}
```

So you'll be able to use `currentUser` from a view:

```
<g:if test="${currentUser.store.isOnline}">
  ...
</g:if>
```

More about filters: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to move this logic to controller and prepare view for that controller (small chunk that you're using for navbar). You can then use `<g:include/>` tag to reuse controller action with that view.

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` will generally pull from 2nd level cache before hitting the database, so that isn't what I'd be concerned with.  The location of your logic is just misplaced.  I'd put your view logic like that in a custom taglib.